# Deleting records without being redirected

Tags: php

Well, I have two files, the first one(users.php) displays the users and put "delete" link next to each user.and the other file(delete.php) delete records when someone clicks on the "delete link".
Here's the delete.php :

```
$user_id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$delete_query = sprintf("DELETE FROM 'tablename' WHERE id = %d", $id);
mysql_query($delete_query);
$msg = "the users has been deleted";
header("Location: http://localhost/intranet/in-admin-panel/users.php?success_message={$msg}");
exit();
```

My problem is, when I made the pagination to paginate the users, I found myself redirected to the first page even when I delete a user in the page3 for exemple(which is obvious from the script)
I tried redirecting to the previous page using($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']), but as I read it's not secure and not practical.
I'm wondering if there is a solution to this issue using php,or I'm forced to learn ajax to do it.

Comment: AJAX is not so hard to learn. Use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. :) Other variant is to use FORM and iframe and target FORM to iframe.

Comment: to save you time, rewriting code, security issues and make life easier, why not use a framework?

Comment: Nice [SQL injection vulnerability](http://bobby-tables.com)... enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that could easily be done with JQuery, check the simple example below:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">

</script>
        <script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    function DeleteItDude() {

                var param = "id=1";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/delete.php",
                    data: param,
                    success: function (msg) {

                        alert(msg)
                    }
                });
}

            $("#lkDelete").click(function () {
                DeleteItDude();
            }

);

 });    
        </script>

<a href="#" id="lkDelete">Delete it Dude</a>
```

and Bang!! you have your delete without refreshing the page.

in case you are not familiar, you will need to use JQuery framework to use the code above. access http://jquery.com/download/ to get the .js file

Comment: That seem nice, I know that I have to learn Ajax, it's just that I have to render my project in few days.So you exemple is all what I need in my case?

Comment: I changed the code below to be clear, it is really simple, this is a simple javascript code using JQuery that submits to delete.php the id to be deleted, you are able to capture the .php results on the success: part. Not a big deal at all

Comment: You'll have to add more code. DeleteItDue() will have to get the correct ID from the DOM element, and it will then have to remove the row from the table. The details depend on how your table is structured.

Comment: While you can do this with PHP alone, this is a good use case for AJAX.  You have a substantial list of items to review and you may wish to act on several.  AJAX can seem intimidating, but especially with jQuery, it's not bad to work with once you get the idea.  The Head-First AJAX book is a good place to start if you're into the books.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you inlude an index in your redirection to the previous page?

```
header("Location: http://localhost/intranet/in-admin-panel/users.php?success_message={$msg}&id{id}");
```

You would need to call delete.php with the actual page as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate all the delete links with a pager number, like this:

```
<a href="delete.php?pager=x">delete</a>
```

Where x corresponds to your page number.

Then when the delete script is done, load the users.php script with the pager value set to the value passed in (x).  Your user script can then resume at the xth page.